# import cycle in golang with test packages

Tags: testing, go

I am trying to refactor some test code and in two packages I need to do the same thing (connect to a DB). I am getting an import cycle. I get why I can't do it, but am wondering what the best way around it is.

Some specifics, I have three packages: `testutils`, `client`, `engine`.

In engine I define an interface & implementation (both exported).

```
package engine
type interface QueryEngine {
  // ...
}
type struct MagicEngine {
  // ...
}
```

And then in the `testutils` package I will create a `MagicEngine` and try and return it.

```
package testutils
func CreateAndConnect() (*engine.MagicEngine, error) {
  // ....
}
```

Now in the test code (using a `TestMain`) I need to do something like

```
package engine
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
  e, err := testutils.CreateAndConnect()
  // ....
  os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

This is of course a cycle. I want to do this so that I can in the `client` package also use this `testutils.CreateAndConnect()` method. I don't want to repeat the code in both packages. I don't want it in the main code of the `engine` package, it is very specific to the tests.

I tried adding it as an exported method on the `engine` test class (`engine/engine_test.go`) and using it in the `client/client_test.go`. No dice. :/

I feel I have done this in other languages, but could be crazy. What is the best way to structure this code for reusability?

Comment: Why can't the CreateAndConnect() function live in the engine package?

Comment: It is purely a test method, it does things around loading the test configuration and test DB.

Comment: So, you could put it in the engine package, but in a *_test.go file. Then it won't be compiled into the production binary, and you avoid the import cycle.

Comment: but then I can't import it in another package's test

Comment: How much logic are we talking about here? A little copy/paste might be ok. Or you could put the CreateAndConnect() function in the engine package so it is exported by other packages. Then just identify the method as a test utility in it's godoc comment. Taking a step back, why do you need initialization logic for tests that is different than production?

Comment: We've worked around this by creating packages that only serve to hold test utilities. Just name them something obvious so that nobody uses them in non-test code.

Comment: Maybe put the CreateAndConnect factory function in the engine package with parameters that accept the test-related dependencies. A function in the test util package can set up and return the test-related dependencies without knowing anything about the engine package, and then TestMain can pass those dependencies into the factory function in the engine, where the new engine instance is created with those dependencies.

Comment: I have been trying things like that - but the problem still comes up when I make methods like `testutils.LoadTestConfig()` and also have some test implementations of the `Engine`. It seems that the coarse grained package inspection doesn't like that. 
-- for now I am repeating sections of code.

Answer (score 4):

You could use black-box style testing because the components of engine are exported.  Change your tests to be in package engine_test:

```
package engine_test
import "engine"
import "testutils"
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
  e, err := testutils.CreateAndConnect()
  // ....
  os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```